# Arangodb "FATAL Database upgrade check failed for"

Tags: arangodb

The arangodb is showing the following error after computer reboot
"FATAL Database upgrade check failed for 'mydatabase'" Please inspect the logs from any errors

i had reinstalled the arangodb, and then, running in first time it was ok, but when I  reboot the computer it didn´t start anymore

in the log file was this log messages

´´
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO ArangoDB 2.2.0 -- ICU 52.1, V8 3.16.14, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO using default language 'en'
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO loaded database '_system' from '/var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-70153'
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO loaded database 'mydatabase' from '/var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-60101129'
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO running WAL recovery
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO dropping database 'mydatabase', directory '/var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-60101129'
2014-07-18T14:49:46Z [6405] INFO creating database 'mydatabase', directory '/var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-60101129'
2014-07-18T14:49:47Z [6405] INFO WAL recovery finished successfully
2014-07-18T14:49:47Z [6405] INFO using endpoint 'tcp://0.0.0.0:8529' for non-encrypted requests
2014-07-18T14:49:47Z [6405] INFO using default API compatibility: 20200
2014-07-18T14:49:47Z [6405] INFO JavaScript using startup '/usr/share/arangodb/js', modules '/usr/share/arangodb/js/server/modules;/usr/share/arangodb/js/common/modules;/usr/share/arangodb/js/node', actions '/usr/share/arangodb/js/actions', application '/var/lib/arangodb-apps'
2014-07-18T14:49:47Z [6405] FATAL Database upgrade check failed for 'mydatabase'. Please inspect the logs from any errors

sorry for my bad english

Comment: That is some sort of linux? Debian? Ubuntu?

Comment: If so, can you try the following "/etc/init.d/arangodb stop" and then "/usr/sbin/arangodb --log.file -"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the start script under Unix. As a workaround can you edit the file /etc/init.d/arangodb and replace the lines

```
$DAEMON -c $CONF --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --check-version
RETVAL=$?
```

by

```
RETVAL=0
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/init.d/arangodb now has this section to resolve your problem:

```sh
            if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 0 ];  then
                $DAEMON --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --pid-file "$PIDFILE" --temp.path "/var/tmp/arangod" --log.foreground-tty false  --supervisor $@
                RETVAL=$?
                log_end_msg $RETVAL
            else
                log_failure_msg "database version check failed, maybe you need to run 'upgrade'?"
            fi
```